# PropertyChangedEventHandler does not work

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a following label and a slider in my UserControl xaml

```
<Label x:Name="labelValX" Content="{Binding Path=xValue}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="88" Height="44"/>

 <Slider x:Name="sliderSpeed" Value="{Binding slideValue, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="173" Height="53" Minimum="10" Maximum="100" />
```

and a specific SetGetAccValues.cs class:

```
public class SetGetAccValues : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private string _xval;
    public string xValue
    {
        get { return _xval; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _xval)
            {
                _xval = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("xValue");
            }
        }
    }

    public byte _slideValue;  
    public byte slideValue {
            get
            {
                return _slideValue;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _slideValue)
                {
                    _slideValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("slideValue");
                }
            }
          }


   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
   {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
       {
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
           if (propName.Equals("slideValue"))
           {
           speedAccMeter(slideValue); 
           }
       }
   }
```

An in my other GetAccNotifications.cs class, I have following part, where I'm defining my xValue string to a specific value:

```
Y = ((double)(sbyte)value) / 64.0;
Y = Math.Round(Y, 2);
SetGetAccValues set = new SetGetAccValues();
set.xValue = Y.ToString();
```

The problem occurs when the OnPropertyChanged is triggered with "xValue" as the propName, the PropertyChangedEventHandler remains always null, but when it is triggered with "slideValue" as propName it is actually not null. Why does it remain null in the xValue case ?.

Comment: What do you mean PropertyChangedEventHandler remains always null?
Are you hooking up an event handler to the PropertyChanged event?
for example: set.PropertyChanged += SetGetAccValuesPropertyChanged;

Comment: I mean that PropertyChanged is always null, so I can't access into the "if" block.

Comment: That means you're not hooking up an event handler to the SetGetAccValues object.  Can you post the relevant code for when you create this object?

Comment: Do you mean the code in the GetAccNotifications class ?. 

I have only defined following lines:

SetGetAccValues set = new SetGetAccValues();
set.xValue = Y.ToString();

Comment: Correct, see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. Do I have to write anything in the SetGetAccValuesPropertyChanged method ?. I have defined the dataContext in my xaml to SetGetAccValues class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64743/discussion-between-michael-g-and-user3812509).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the PropertyChanged event is firing before the datacontext is finished loading.

You can listen to the DataContextChanged event in your usercontrol, so that when the new datacontext is available, you can set your properties.

```
public AccView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;

    this.DataContext = new SetGetAccValues();    
}

private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    Y = ((double)(sbyte)value) / 64.0;
    Y = Math.Round(Y, 2);

    (dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue as SetGetAccValues).xValue = Y.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I can't move the Y-value in the SetGetAccValues class, since it is triggered and defined as a value in the GetAccNotifications class

Comment: How is the SetGetAccValues being added to the GetAccNotifications view?

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't bind DataContext. You should set DataContext with code behind in your case.

**In SetGetAccValues.xaml.cs**

```
    public SetGetAccValues()
    {       
        DataContext = this;
    }
```